# How to execute COM+ libraries from Java using a free method

Tags: java, com+

I have a COM+ component developed with VB6.

After registering it with the component services manager COM+ application, I can use it from ASP like this

```
Set Comando = Server.CreateObject("JuiciosComando.clsComando")
ComandoExecute = Comando.execute(Xml)
Set Comando = Nothing
```

That's all I need, the component just receives a (maybe a huge) string and returns another (also possibly huge) string...

Is there some way to access this very same component from Java?

What I've found so far is [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/servlet_com/ServletToComPlusExample.html) but it's a commercial product.

I've also found [this thread on codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-383429.html) but my C++.NET knowledge is rather poor, besides I would rather just find a free, pure Java solution.

Comment: I swear I thought this said "how to ejaculate com+ libraries". I need some sleep.

Comment: @KevDog: and the OP needs a spell-checker ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Eddie mentioned,  you have two main  methods of using COM via java: using C++ and writing a JNI wrapper or using a third party JAR to wrap the COM object.

I've attempted to use C++ to wrap a COM object in the past - it's not for the faint hearted - it is not easy to do and its very easy to leak resources.

I've also used two third party JAR's: ComfyJ and JACOB.

ComfyJ was really easy to use and also included a codegen utility to generate java wrapper classes for your COM classes.

It can be downloaded and trialed via http://www.teamdev.com/comfyj/index.jsf

(I am not affiliated with TeamDev in any way!)

If you are desperate for a totally free solution, you could also try JACOB (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

I had issues with documentation, but it was relatively stable.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) works pretty well. I've used it for numerous COM automation projects without any issues. And it's free...

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with an application that originally tried JNI to interact with native code to access COM, and it ended up being very very difficult to maintain and debug.  (Fortunately, I wasn't the person working on that part of the application!) As a result of this experience, I now recommend that Java code needing to access COM do it by writing a C# application to do COM access, and use a nailed-up socket between the two applications.

JNI is unnecessarily risky and difficult in Java, as compared to the equivalent in C#, so the most stable way to do this from Java is to not do it from Java.  Delegate the COM access to something that has expertise in COM access:  C#.

Your other alternative is to license some 3rd party library that itself manages the JNI for you.  But unless you enjoy pain, I highly recommend against rolling your own JNI solution.

Added later:  As you see in the link you referenced, JNI code can crash the entire JVM.  At least if the COM access is at the other end of a socket, if the C# application crashes, you only lose your socket which you can easily reestablish when the C# application returns.  However, C# is **far** less likely to crash when accessing COM.  Yes, it's nicer to have a pure 100% Java solution, but sometimes it's really a lot better to delegate tasks to another language.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try com4j which works great for me and supports also com events. You can find it here: https://com4j.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this thread is old, but j-Interop could help you out.

*From the **j-interop.org** website:*

> "j-Interop is a Java Open Source
>   library (under LGPL) that implements
>   the DCOM wire protocol (MSRPC) to
>   enable development of Pure,
>   Bi-Directional, Non-Native Java
>   applications which can interoperate
>   with any COM component."

Cheers,
Matt